# Homomorphic Decryption with the Encryption (ciphertext) of Secret key for Bootstrapping purpose

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, decryption

The section 3.1 of the [GHS11](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/680.pdf) mentions that:

> Given the $q_L$-ciphertext $c = (c_0, c_1)$ (that encrypts a polynomial $a \in F_2[X]/F(X)$), we postprocess it to get $c^\prime = (c_0 + c^*, c_1) \text{ mod } 2^{r + 1}$ as above, and then use the encryption of $s$ from the public key to compute the simple decryption formula from above. Computing an encryption of $Z^\prime = [\langle c^\prime, s \rangle \text{ mod } F(X)]_{2^{r+1}}$ is easy, since the coefficients of $Z^\prime$ are just affine functions (over $Z/2^{r+1}Z$) of the coefficients of s, which we can compute from the encryption of the $s_j$'s in the public key.

I have two questions here for any altruistic people.

They have taken each coefficient $s_j$ of the secret key $s$, encrypted them as a constant polynomial and generated a ciphertext $\tilde{c_{j}}$. Thus they have $d$ number of ciphertexts, $\tilde{c_{0}}, \tilde{c_{1}}, \cdots, \tilde{c_{d-1}}$, where $d$ is the power of the secret key polynomial.

1. How do they generate the encryption of secret key ($s$) from a bunch of ciphertexts: $\tilde{c_{0}}, \tilde{c_{1}}, \cdots, \tilde{c_{d-1}}$? Like, adding them together or so? Or possibly, we don't need to combine them, instead we can use these individual encryptions of secret key's coefficients for homomorphic decryption?
2. How do they homomorphically decrypt to get $Z^\prime = [\langle c^\prime, s \rangle \text{ mod } F(X)]_{2^{r+1}}$? I.e., computing the inner product between $c^\prime$ and the encryption of $s$?

I would really appreciate any help to understand the topic. Or, am I missing anything?